# Mysql - subquery have more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with my query.
Here is my db and my query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4219/17

If user have more than 3 song i want to select with limit 3,3.

if less than 3 select all for specific user

update:

I no need always first 3 songs, this offset in limit in second query is really important for me (in my real problem i use "order by" so normal limit with offset return me another rows than first 3). Maybe you have another idea to solve my problem:

if user have more than 3 songs then return 3 songs but not first 3 (need limit 3,3). I must have this in one query i cant use php etc.

Comment: If less than 3, select all means select all from the table or select all for that particular user_id?

Comment: for the particular user. sry. example is updated

Comment: Then no need of the case statement. simply give limit.. Check @Mithun Sasidharan answer.

Comment: my problem is more advenced, I need some if condition to one program which use only xml with sql loop. I must have it in one query

Comment: Please copy your code here. If the external resource disappears, your question becomes meaningless.

Comment: Are you sure of your `LIMIT 3,3`? (i.e. three songs starting from the fourth one) Don't you want `LIMIT 3`?

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

`SELECT * From SONGS where USER_ID = 1 LIMIT 3;`

If it's less, it'll give less, if it's more it'll give 3 and if you want a specific set of the 3, just order the set

Answer (score 0):

Inside a SELECT CASE WHEN you must return a single "value" or line/record.
In your case, the THEN and ELSE can and will return multiple lines for user_id = 1

Your code works fine but only for user_id = 3 since he has one song only.

To make it work, just use the simple LIMIT 3 operator which returns **all** the rows the query found, **up to a maximum of 3**.

Your code should be like

```
select song from songs where user_id = 1
```

Obviously you might want to use a parameter to the query on whichever platform you are constructing the interogation instead of user_id = hardcoded_value.

[More information about select limit](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

Comment: my problem is more advenced, I need some "if condition" to one program which use only xml with sql loop. I must have it in one query, i no need always first 3 songs, this offset in limit in second query is really important for me

Comment: In that case you might want to edit your question and add the full problem and scenario because the answers given to you up until now solve your initial question.